# What's the meaning of io_event.res2 parameter in asynchronous file IO?

Tags: linux

I am using asynchronous IO api in my project, i am confused of the parameters `io_event.res` and `io_event.res2`

it seams that res means the io size, but what's the meaning of res2. Comments that i found in the file `/usr/include/linux/aio.abi.h` help nothing.

I will appriciate it so much if anyone explain that and shwo us an example.

```
/* read() from /dev/aio returns these structures. */
struct io_event {
        __u64           data;           /* the data field from the iocb */
        __u64           obj;            /* what iocb this event came from */
        __s64           res;            /* result code for this event */
        __s64           res2;           /* secondary result */
};
```

my code as below

```
size_t nevents = 2;
struct io_event events[nevents];
ret = io_getevents(ioctx, 1, nevents, events, NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("io_getevents");
    exit(1);
}

for (size_t i=0; i<ret; i++) {
    struct io_event *ev = &events[i];
    printf("Event returned with res=%lld res2=%lld\n", ev->res, ev->res2);
    nevents--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

res return the size of succeed io operation. if failed,res return the negative errno